# Adding the ID or class into the exact match element

Tags: jquery, arrays, if-statement, filter, jquery-selectors

Hi there I am expanding on my previous post: [Jquery matching values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61467823/jquery-matching-values/61471047?noredirect=1#comment108800583_61471047). I was wondering if anyone knows how to have this also filter the ID or Class as it is doing with the data value. I am trying to build a filter like this in the end and have repeating elements show how many times they are repeated. I use TWIG for the HTML from Advanced Custom Fields Wordpress plugin.

Eventually I want this to be a dropdown like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I06cT.png you can refer to this post: [Building a dropdown select filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61505353/building-a-dropdown-select-filter). Let me know if you have any direction how i should proceed! Thank you!!

I am also trying to make this sort both alphabetically for the locations and sort by date for the date section. This is the format of the date: February 26, 2020.

HTML:

```
<div class="filter" name="course-location" id="course-location">
  <div class="upper-filter"><h3>Locations</h3><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
  <div class="filter-dropdown">
  {% for category in bloc.training_course_list_compact.course_categories %}
  {% for locationcourse in category.get_field('courses') %}
  {% for location in locationcourse.get_field('dates') %}
    <div class="course-location {{ category.category_class }}" id="{{ category.category_class }}" data-value="{{ location.location }}"><span class="{{ locationcourse.course_title }}"></span></div>
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  <div class="class-location type-filter"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="filter" name="course-date" id="course-date">
  <div class="upper-filter"><h3>Start Date</h3><i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i></div>
  <div class="filter-dropdown">
  {% for category in bloc.training_course_list_compact.course_categories %}
  {% for datecourse in category.get_field('courses') %}
  {% for dates in datecourse.get_field('dates') %}
    <div class="course-date {{ category.category_class }}" id="{{ category.category_class }}" data-value="{{ dates.date }}"><span class="{{ locationcourse.course_title }}"></span></div>
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  <div class="class-date type-filter"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
  //Location Filter
  // Extract the values to an array
  $("#course-location").each(function() {
    let locations = $('.course-location').map((i, e) => $(e).data('value')).toArray();

    let reducer = (a, c) => {
      // If the city doesn't exist 
      a[c] === undefined ?
        a[c] = 1 : // One occurrence, else
        a[c] = a[c] + 1;  // Increment count
      return a;
    }

    let location_count = locations.reduce(reducer, {});

    // Create HTML Elements
    for (var place in location_count) {
      $('.class-location').append(`<div class="inner-info"><h4>${place}</h4><span>${location_count[place]}</span></div>`)
    }
  });

  //Date Filter
  // Extract the values to an array
  $("#course-date").each(function() {
    let date = $('.course-date').map((i, e) => $(e).data('value')).toArray();

    let reducer = (a, c) => {
      // If the date doesn't exist 
      a[c] === undefined ?
        a[c] = 1 : // One occurrence, else
        a[c] = a[c] + 1;  // Increment count
      return a;
    }

    let date_count = date.reduce(reducer, {});

    // Create HTML Elements
    for (var dates in date_count) {
      $('.class-date').append(`<div class="inner-info"><h4>${dates}</h4><span>${date_count[dates]}</span></div>`)
    }
  });
```

Comment: `$("#course-date").each` <= this logic is an immediate code smell.  Ids are expected to be unique by web standards, and this selector will only find the first one on the page.  If you find yourself in a situation with repeating ids, you need to fix that issue first by converting them to classes.

Comment: Same thing with `{{ category.category_class }}`, this is bound to have repeats, unless they are unique, but then no point in having them as the `class` attribute, too. What do you mean by "**also filter**"? Filter what? Can you post a small data sample and expected output?